# Why does clear only apply to block-level elements?

Tags: css

So the CSS 2.1 Spec states that:

> 'clear'
>   Applies to:     block-level elements

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-clear

But is there any reason I cannot use this for inline elements?

Comment: Do inline elements not automatically clear ? Are you trying to achieve something specific or just curious about this ?

Comment: You mean inline elements can automatically clear? Actually I'm just curious why.

Answer (score 0):

Inline elements makes use of text-align instead of floats... makes no sense to clear them.